# How can I write to an excel file continuously?

Tags: c#, excel, createfile

I would like to create and write continuosly to an Excel file. I have to code below, but I want to add all the datas which I get continuously.

CODE:

```
        Excel.Application xlApp ;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "http://csharp.net-informations.com";

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs("csharp-Excel.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        //xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);

        MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file c:\\csharp-Excel.xls");
    }

    private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " +     ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

In this code, when start the application, it always says that do you wanna replace it and it always closes the application when the program gets the data.

This is the functionality which I want to have: I want to append the file like here.

```
    StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter("test.txt", true);
    fileWriter.WriteLine(jointHead.Position.X);       
    fileWriter.Close();
```

What can be the solution for this kind of problem? 
Thank you...

Comment: I would consider writing a text file that is in a format compatible with excel such as csv, and appending to that continuously. You'll probably find it much quicker and simpler.

Comment: btw - i know that your MessageBox.Show("Exception...") is prolly for debugging purposes. make sure not to leave that in place in your final app and instead think of some kind of logging functionality with an 'importance' enum attached. other than that, i would be tempted to ask why the excel file is being used rather thsn other scalable storage mediums. you could after all, query a db and present an excel file with the content where required. added as answer as well

Comment: Because, I have 60 columns and around 400 rows data...That's why I wanted to use excel. I didnt want to create tables,rows and columns...Firstly I tried just txt file. It appends it perfectly. But, if you have sooooo much data, it looks messy. It is difficult to choose some data between them. That's why I wanted to use excel.It already has columns and rows. I didnt need to create tables. Do you have any solution for this purpose?

Comment: samet - i still don't agree with your approach - sorry. however, my alternative solution would be to look at saving the data in memory (cache), or preferably onto the db and then output it to your form via a listview. i appreciate that you'd like an excel based solution but i simply would not recommend that as in my experience EVERYTHING get's ramped up beyond your initial expectations and given that you are coding directly to an implementation, rather than an interface, this doesn't bode well for refactoring should 'demand' ramp up.

Comment: I dont want to make it more difficult just to save some data. I mean I dont want to use db. The solution should be offline...According to this goal, I'm looking for your answer again.

Answer (score 0):

To append the file use this code insead:

```
using(StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(@"c:\test.txt", true))
{
    fileWriter.WriteLine("test");
}
```

Otherwise you will not write anything to the file because you close it before it has written to it. This will append the file and close the stream in the right way.

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) is a link to a tutorial on linq to sql. This might help you find a god solution for save and loading data

Comment: I wanted to show the idea, I use sth different at the begining. I have 60 columns and around 400 rows data. Thats why I didnt want to use text file. Do you have any soluiton for the rows and columns?

Comment: Like said before. I would probably go with a database table and save it there. If it is a requirement to show the changes in a excel sheet then you can just read from the database and present it in a excel document.

Comment: Can you give me some link or some sample code of database table? I have never done anything about database table so far. Also, it's not a requirement to show in excel. It was just my idea to show it in tables. Because there are so many data. By the way, I'm not getting the data from database, lets say that, these are the positions of mouse and other devives.

Comment: It's better not to use db. Solution should be offline if you have ?

Comment: No it doesn't matter you can use a database if your solution is offline (local database) or online.

Answer (score 0):

Excel files are binary, so writing continuously to an Excel file doesn't really make sense.

The best solution I can suggest is to create a CSV file, and continuously write to that instead. Unlike Excel files, CSV files can be treated as simple text streams and can be opened natively by Excel.

Comment: I have 60 columns and around 400 rows data...That's why I wanted to use excel. I didnt want to create tables...Do you have any solution for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

btw - i know that your MessageBox.Show("Exception...") is prolly for debugging purposes. make sure not to leave that in place in your final app and instead think of some kind of logging functionality with an 'importance' enum attached.

other than that, i would be tempted to ask why the excel file is being used rather than other scalable storage mediums. you could after all, save to a db, query it when required and present an excel file with the filtered content. that way, you don't run the risk of exceeding the excel row maximum, which isn't catered for in your error handling, other than in the general releaseObject() try{}/catch{}.

just my scottish belt and braces attitude :)